# is my bash script correct?

Tags: bash

My server is centos 5.7. I need a script work with cron job that auto restarts mysql service once the memory usage reaches 55%.

Is below script correct?

```
#!/bin/bash

TOTAL=`free | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}'`
USED=`free | grep buffers\/cache | awk '{print $3}'`
let PERCENT=$USED*100/$TOTAL

if [ $PERCENT -gt 55 ]; then
    service mysqld restart
fi
```

Comment: Did you try this on your server?  What were the results?

Comment: @ABach  I know nothing on bash, I get this script via google. I am just not sure whether the script is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's basic but correct.

A more complete and robust approach would be to just install [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), which can perform actions on conditions like this and also provides other services.

Comment: to me ,Monit is more difficult to configure

Comment: @EdwardHuang: it is more difficult, true, but you get monitoring and alerts built in. Also, a one-shot cronjob can't easily make a decision based on data from past runs (there is no "state"). But hey, I'd lie if I said I haven't written or used dozens of scripts like the one you posted :)